# c++ search text n boolean mode

Tags: c++, regex, full-text-search, boolean-expression

basically have two questions.
1. Is there a c++ library that would do full text boolean search just like in mysql. E.g.,
Let's say I have:

```
string text = "this is my phrase keywords test with boolean query."; 
string booleanQuery = "\"my phrase\" boolean -test -\"keywords test\" OR ";
       booleanQuery += "\"boolean search\" -mysql -sql -java -php"b

//where quotes ("") contain phrases, (-) is NOT keyword and OR is logical OR.
```

If answer to first is no, then;
2. Is it possible to search a phrase in text. e.g.,

```
string text =//same as previous
string keyword = "\"my phrase\"";

//here what's the best way to search for my phrase in the text?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TR1 has a regex class (derived from `Boost::regex`). It's not quite like you've used above, but reasonably close. `Boost::phoenix` and `Boost::Spirit` also provide similar capabilities, but for a first attempt the Boost/TR1 regex class is probably a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

As to the 2nd point: `string` class does have a method `find`, see http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/find

Comment: Thanks Piotr, I'm using string::find method. However, problem is, I want to be able to search keyword/phrases with punctutions as well. Right now I am doing following, but there must be a better way:  
vector<string> ext;   
ext.push_back((" "+keyword+" "));    
ext.push_back((" "+keyword+", "));    
ext.push_back((" "+keyword+". "));    
ext.push_back((" "+keyword+"."));    
.....    
.....    
for(vector<string>::const_iterator it=ext.begin(); it!=ext.end();  ++it){    
  if(text.find(*it) != string::npos)    
    return true;   
}   
return fasle;

Comment: You need only to do text.find(keyword) — find searches for *string* (as in sequence of characters, not just word) and is oblivious to what is adjacent to any occurrence of that string, be it punctuation or anything else.

Comment: The problems with this approach is if I have a text = "this is a test". text.find("hi") will return 1 eventhout I am searching for "hi" not any occurance of "hi" within text. Find looks for any string match within the text and thus fails to find exact keywords/phrases within text.

Comment: Searching for "hi" is misleading the way you understand it. You want to search for word "hi", instead of subsequence. If you want to use word boundaries, you will need to use regular expressions, like in other answers here.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is, try Spirit:

http://boost-spirit.com/home/